# Как использовать yii::t(); в js-файлах?

Tags: php, yii2

Как в `js`-файлах использовать функцию `yii::t();`? Например, как перевести "отмена" в этом куске js-кода:

```
"btn-primary cancel-comment'>Отмена</button><button type='button' class='btn "
```

проблема только с переводом `js`-файлов, в `php` файлах - все ок.

**Update**

Беда именно в том, что в данном случае нет вьюх, есть только `js`-файлики для модальных окон с кнопочками "закрыть" , "сохранить" и так далее... Я очень слаб в `js`, по-этому, если вас не затруднит, можно ли поподробней касательно "аналогичной" функции на `js` - пример какой-нить что ли.

Comment: А вообще с `yii::t()` вы работать умеете? Настраивали? В `php` файлах применяли? Проблема только с `js` скриптами или вообще не  настроен перевод тоже?

Comment: Если говорить именно о ФАЙЛАХ отдельных, то никак. Это же ПХП функция.... Только делать аналогичную функцию на JS. Если говорить о `javascript` коде во вьюхах, то делать также, как Обычно `<?= Yii::t('translateCatalog', 'translateTag'); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Имхо делать надо руками, в Yii вроде ничего такого изкоробки не было на тему прокидывания словарей в js. Если такое нужно только эпизодически, то можно даже просто через переменную вроде такого во вьюхе:

```
$this->registerJs("var cancelText = '". Yii::t('app', 'Отмена') . "';", \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD);
```

и соотв-но в js подставлять текст из переменной cancelText...

Если мыслить чуть глобальнее, то наверное есть смысл сразу вести/генерить дублирующий словарь в js с небольшой оберткой, аналогичной по функционалу Yii::t() и подключать этот словарь наряду с остальным js-кодом, прокидывая из бэкенда требуемую локаль.